# Swift から Objective-C の構造体のメンバにアクセスする方法

Tags: objective-c, swift

Swift から Objective-C の構造体のメンバにアクセスする方法は、どうすれば良いでしょうか？

【Objective-C】

```c
struct test {
    char        *test_name;
};

extern int getifaddrs(struct test **);
```

【Swift】

```
var work : UnsafeMutablePointer<test>;

var ret:int_fast32_t = 0
ret=getifaddrs(&work)
```

ここで、`work` の中の `test_name` メンバにアクセスしたいのですが出てきませんでした。

```
work.
```

Comment: ポインタ（UnsafePointer、UnsafeMutablePointer）の指す値は、プロパティmemoryで取得します。`work.memory`

Comment: ご回答、ありがとうございます。
取得できました。

Comment: @Harawo 質問の適切な回答になっているようなので、コメントではなく回答として投稿して頂ければと思います。

Comment: @tomute すみません、サンプルコード込みで回答しようとしているのですが、なかなかビルドをとおるサンプルコードが書けなくて……

Comment: @Harawo そうでしたか。ではサンプルコードが出来たら回答にして頂ければと思います。急ぎではありませんので。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UnsafePointer、UnsafeMutablePointerは、プロパティ「memory」を使って、ポイントする値を取得できます。

以下、サンプルコード。

Objective-Cファイル：

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
// 構造体の定義
typedef struct test {
    int number;
} Test;
// 構造体のポインタを返す関数。基本Swiftは、ポインタが「ない」ことになってるので、C側でポインタを作る必要があります。
Test *getPointer(Test *value) {
    return value;
}
// ポインタのポインタを引数にとる関数
int inputTwo(Test **theTest) {
    (*theTest)->number = 2;
    return 2;
}
```

Swiftファイル：ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // 構造体Test型の変数myTestを宣言して、初期化。それからTest型ポインタmyPointerを作成。
        var myTest = Test(number: 0)
        var myPointer :UnsafeMutablePointer<Test> = getPointer(&myTest)
        // ポインタのポインタを引数にとる関数に渡す。
        let result = inputTwo(&myPointer)
        // プロパティ「memory」で、ポインタが指し示している構造体を取得。
        let resultTest = myPointer.memory
        println(result)
        // Swiftの構造体と同じ扱いで、構造体の要素にアクセスできます。
        println(resultTest.number)
    }
}
```

Comment: 構造体のポインタを取得するところは withUnsafeMutablePointer を使うと、Cの関数を使わずに、Swiftだけで var myPointer = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&myTest) { $0 } のように書くこともできます。